# Stop watch and timer

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdate, nstimer

I want to use NSDate and NSTimer to retrieve the elapsed time between I press a start button and a stop button and present the time in seconds. Then I want to use the time for a calculation. I know how to get the time but it is always in format like this 2013-01-15 14:01:55.369.
How do I subtract one time from the other to get the seconds.
I am not sure how to use NDDate and NSTimer.
This should be really easy but I am sort of stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Make two properties `NSDate *startDate, *endDate`

//in the action method of start Button 
startDate=[NSDate date];

//in the action method of stop Button
stopDate=[NSDate date];
long elapsedSeconds=[stopDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
NSLog(@"Elaped seconds:%ld seconds",elapsedSeconds);
```

Please check my [project](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/5387039/timerstopwatch-3-zip-43k?da=y) for stopwatch kind of thing, this may come handy for you

Check this code, most of requirement are solved here.

Comment: It was the following which made the trick for me. Thanks.               self.startDate =[NSDate date];
    if (!self.timer) {
        self.timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(timerDisplay) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

Comment: I am really sorry because it was a perfect answer which helped me a lot. Thanks again. Then you may be could tell me how to compare a timer value from one timing until next timing. One start and stop until next start and stop. So it remembers the first round until next to compare with.

Comment: You can check in my stopwatch project. A simple logic in planted there. You need something similar to this `pauseTime=totalTime-timerRunnintime`.

Comment: ok. Will do that. Will let you know. May be not right know but later today I hope

Comment: I solved the issue comparing the variables within a block from one time until another. Used property, synthesize and the old value was still available.

Comment: But your project was to great help. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceDate:(NSDate *)date
```

to get the time interval between the receiver and a given date in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

To get current time from NSData use:

```
[[NSData data] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

and just substract it from your NSTime value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `timeIntervalSinceDate` between the start date and en stop date.